# pandas cut: how to convert categorical labels to strings (otherwise cannot export to Excel)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I use pandas.cut() to discretise a continuous variable into a range, and then group by the result.

After a lot of swearing because I couldn't figure out what was wrong, I have learnt that, if I don't supply custom labels to the cut() function, but rely on the default, then the output cannot be exported to excel. If I try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
wk = writer.book.add_worksheet('Test')

df= df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df['range'] = pd.cut( df['a'],[-np.inf,3,8,np.inf] )
grouped=df.groupby('range').sum()
grouped.to_excel(writer, 'Export')
writer.close()
```

I get:

```
raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'> in write()
which it took me a while to decypher.
```

If instead I do assign labels:

```
df['range'] = pd.cut( df['a'],[-np.inf,3,8,np.inf], labels =['<3','3-8','>8'] )
```

then it all runs fine.
Any suggestions on how to handle this without assigning custom labels? In the initial phase of my work I tend not to assign labels, because I still don't know how many bins I want - it's a trial and error approach, and assigning labels at each attempt would be time-consuming.

I am not sure if this can count as a bug, but at the very least it seems like a poorly documented annoyance!

Comment: `df['range'] = pd.cut(df['a'],[-np.inf,3,8,np.inf], labels =['<3','3-8','>8']).astype(str)`

Comment: The question was how to do it WITHOUT assigning labels explicitly

Comment: you can leave off the `labels` kwargs, AFAIK

Comment: You have not read my question. If I leave out the labels, then I cannot export the Excel - this was the question!! I need to do astype(str) as per the answer below.

Comment: that's exactly what i was suggesting with my second comment

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `astype(str)`:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
wk = writer.book.add_worksheet('Test')

df= df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df['range'] = pd.cut( df['a'],[-np.inf,3,8,np.inf] ).astype(str)
grouped=df.groupby('range').sum()
grouped.to_excel(writer, 'Export')
writer.close()
```

Output in excel:

```
range   a   b   c   d   e
(-inf, 3.0] 6798    17277   16979   17266   16949
(3.0, 8.0]  33150   28051   27551   27692   27719
(8.0, inf]  9513    5153    5318    5106    5412
```

[image]